# php how to fetch multiple records and display in a query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a partner table and I need to send reply via SMS. So my table contains firm name, city, mobile and pincode. If someone sends me a pin code via SMS, I want to get back to the customer with the 2 or 3 records (Multiple). With this code I am able to send only one record.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reg_dealer WHERE pincode = '$myvalue'";
$q = mysql_query($sql);
$rows= mysql_num_rows($q);
$res= mysql_fetch_array($q);

$firm_name=$res['firm_name'];
$city=$res['city'];
$mobiledealer=$res['mobile'];
$pincode=$res['pincode'];

if($res['pincode']=='')
{
$mobile = $_GET['mobile'];  
$reply_message = "Greeting. We will get back to you soon on the nearest Partner details.";
$reply_message1 = urlencode($reply_message);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO history(sender,message,datetime,datenew,code,status,reply_message,url)VALUES('$mobile','$message','$datetime','$datenew','$number','Dealer Does Not Exist','$reply_message','$s')");//insert data in to table
}
// part 2
else
{
$mobile = $_GET['mobile'];  
$reply_message = "Greetings. Please find the nearest Partner - ".$firm_name.", ".$city.", +".$mobiledealer.".";
$reply_message1 = urlencode($reply_message);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO history(sender,message,datetime,datenew,code,status,reply_message,url)VALUES('$mobile','$message','$datetime','$datenew','$number','Dealer Details Sent','$reply_message','$s')");//insert data in to table
}
```

Comment: If there is only one record with that pincode it will return that row only.

Comment: PHP's mysql_ API was deprecated about 100 years ago. So, come on, join the 21st century.

Comment: Do not use mysql_* now. Use PDO or Mysqli.

Comment: loop through the result using this -  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) or even you can use group_concat

Comment: if you are new and not familier with mysqli/PDO, use this for secure sql connection: https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use while loop.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reg_dealer WHERE pincode = '$myvalue'";
$q = mysql_query($sql);
$rows= mysql_num_rows($q);
while($res= mysql_fetch_array($q))
{

$firm_name=$res['firm_name'];
$city=$res['city'];
$mobiledealer=$res['mobile'];
$pincode=$res['pincode'];

if($res['pincode']=='')
{
$mobile = $_GET['mobile'];  
$reply_message = "Greeting. We will get back to you soon on the nearest Partner details.";
$reply_message1 = urlencode($reply_message);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO history(sender,message,datetime,datenew,code,status,reply_message,url)VALUES('$mobile','$message','$datetime','$datenew','$number','Dealer Does Not Exist','$reply_message','$s')");//insert data in to table
}
// part 2
else
{
$mobile = $_GET['mobile'];  
$reply_message = "Greetings. Please find the nearest Partner - ".$firm_name.", ".$city.", +".$mobiledealer.".";
$reply_message1 = urlencode($reply_message);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO history(sender,message,datetime,datenew,code,status,reply_message,url)VALUES('$mobile','$message','$datetime','$datenew','$number','Dealer Details Sent','$reply_message','$s')");//insert data in to table
}  
}
```

> Update with new requirement:

```
$mobile = $_GET['mobile'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reg_dealer WHERE pincode = '$myvalue'";
    $q = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows= mysql_num_rows($q);
    while($res= mysql_fetch_array($q))
    {

    $firm_name=$res['firm_name'];
    $city=$res['city'];
    $mobiledealer=$res['mobile'];
    $pincode=$res['pincode'];

    if($res['pincode']=='')
    {
    $reply_message .= "Greeting. We will get back to you soon on the nearest Partner details.";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO history(sender,message,datetime,datenew,code,status,reply_message,url)VALUES('$mobile','$message','$datetime','$datenew','$number','Dealer Does Not Exist','$reply_message','$s')");//insert data in to table
    }
    // part 2
    else
    {
    $reply_message .= "Greetings. Please find the nearest Partner - ".$firm_name.", ".$city.", +".$mobiledealer.".";
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO history(sender,message,datetime,datenew,code,status,reply_message,url)VALUES('$mobile','$message','$datetime','$datenew','$number','Dealer Details Sent','$reply_message','$s')");//insert data in to table
    }  
    }  
if (isset($reply_message) && $reply_message != '')
{
    $reply_message1 = urlencode($reply_message);

    if($res['pincode']=='')
    {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO history(sender,message,datetime,datenew,code,status,reply_message,url)VALUES('$mobile','$message','$datetime','$datenew','$number','Dealer Does Not Exist','$reply_message1','$s')");//insert data in to table
    }
    // part 2
    else
    {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO history(sender,message,datetime,datenew,code,status,reply_message,url)VALUES('$mobile','$message','$datetime','$datenew','$number','Dealer Details Sent','$reply_message1','$s')");//insert data in to table
    } 
}
```

Comment: hi Chayan, thanks for your help, just tested the code and getting multiple records but only thing is i am getting responce in multiple message is there any way where i can embed all records in a single message.

Comment: yes, just concat all the message and than run your final operation after the loop completed.

Comment: Hi Chayan, thanks for the support but it would be great if you please help me out with concat as well, i have tried but no luck. i am very new into this a help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching only single record because you are not using any type of loop for getting multiple records.

Use while loop:

```
while($res= mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
     //put your below inside the loop
}
```